# Restricting a lookup field in a list

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column, customization

I'm putting on SharePoint Lunch and Learn training for my company.  I'm wanting them to sign up.

In one list, I have title and date

Lunch and Learn 1, January 15

Lunch and Learn 2, January 22

In my other list I want them to sign up, by click on "add a new item" and then they select only "Lunch and Learn 2, January 22

Ideas on solutions would be greatly appreciated.  I'm thinking Java Script of some sort, or even *shudder* infopath.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a lookup column and want to filter the results I would suggest using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation).  Specifically you would be using [$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFilterDropdown).

Description from codeplex:

> The SPFilterDropdown function allows you to filter the values available in a Lookup column using CAML against the Lookup column's source list.  This function works with all three types of "dropdown": <20 options (simple select), 20+ options (complex select), and multi-select.